# Why i'm getting conflict?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table (`test`) with following fields:

```
id (text)
msg (text)
result (bytea)
```

where `id` is defined as index

I'm running the following query:

```
insert into test(id, result) 
values ('t1', 't-res')
on conflict (id) do update
set result = 't-res'
```

but I'm getting:

```
there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the on conflict specification
```

- I can't understand why there is a conflict ?
- How can I fix it ?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the complete `create table` statement for the table in question including all `create index` statements.

Answer (score 0):

You should set `id` as primary key (missing in your question).